# Последовательность букв

Tags: недопустимая-метка, историческая-грамматика, алфавит

Может быть, конечно, у меня вопрос глупый и даже детский. Но вот интересно, по какому принципу выбиралась последовательность букв в алфавите? Почему именно А — первая буква, а Я (в латинице — Z, в греческом — омега) — последняя?

Comment: Детские вопросы, как известно, самые трудные

Comment: А это совсем не детский вопрос. Учитывая сколько вокруг этой самой алфавитной последовательности спекуляций расплодилось, вполне можно ставить на вполне серьёзном уровне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Говорить только о русском алфавите особо не приходится, он списан с греческого с небольшими дополнениями для специфических звуков, в большинстве своем эти дополнительные знаки помещены в конец азбуки.

Греческое письмо, как и все на нем основанные (включая латиницу) восходит к финикийскому. Неизвестно, была ли какая-то утвержденная последовательность знаков в финикийском алфавите, но в первом же его потомке - арамейском она появилась. Учитывая необходимые изменения эта последовательность попала во все современные Европы, Средиземноморья, Северной Африки и Ближнего и Среднего Востока (кроме амхарского). Именно поэтому так похожи последовательности знаков во всех алфавитах этого региона от еврейского и арабского до армянского и грузинского. Например, во всех них звонкие согласные предшествуют в массе глухим.

Насколько мне известно, аналогичный принцип наследственности использован во всех алфавитах, основанных на санскрите и даже в тайском, кхмерском и других "оригинальных" алфавитах.

Несколько иначе обстоит дело с новыми алфавитами для языков, например народов Океании и Африки (фонетически очень далеких от европейских - и требующих своих принципов), и со слоговыми алфавитами некоторых языков Восточной Азии (включая корейский и два японских).

Есть некая утвержденная последовательность знаков даже в китайском (иначе невозможно было бы создавать словари и энциклопедии), вроде бы даже не одна, но объяснять её принципы я не берусь, для этого пришлось бы очень много написать про сам принцип китайского письма и про основы иероглифики. Кроме того, для китайского есть еще несколько составленных европейцами "фонетических" алфавитов на латинском принципе, но они используются в основном в двуязычных словарях. Последовательность знаков в них основана на принципах фонетики китайского слога (иницаль-медиаль-финаль).

Comment: Хороший ответ Бегемотуса (мой клик ему), но более подробно читайте здесь: http://newciv.relarn.ru/work/2-09/bukvi/book.htm Эта версия напомнила мне школу...

Comment: Пожалуй, версия по ссылке уж слишком краткая. История-то давняя!

Comment: Соан, помилуйте, я отвечал на конкретный вопрос о *последовательности букв*, причем не только в русском. Пресказывать всю историрия самого алфавита от братьев солунских до наших дней в мою задачу не входило. Но если уж говорить об алфавите, то по Вашей ссылке действительно очень уж примитино изложена эта история.   
Вот несколько совершенно неосвещенныз фопросов.
1. Создание "дополнительных букв"
2. Полемика вокруг письмен черноризца Храбра (преподанаоого там совершенно однобоко)
3. Глаголица и кириллица. Отнюдь не лющепризнано то, что там сказано.
и т.д.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus! Мы не занимаемся исследовательской работой в широком смысле. Отвечаем лаконично, с чувством, с толком, с расстановкой. И ничего нет преступного в том, что данная ссылка напомнила мне школьное изложение этого вопроса. Я же не претендую на полный ответ (у меня все-таки комментарий!) - Вашего достаточно.

Comment: Уважаемый Соан! Я не претендую на понимание Вашего комментария. 
Меня же в первую очередь интересовало, что ж такого не хватало в моём ответе, чтобы признать его достаточно полным. На будущее так сказать. А вашего источника я коснулся "постольку поскольку". И вот именно он мне показался несколько куцым и однобоким в рамках заявленной в нем темы. О чем я и сказал.

Answer (score 0):

Буквы - знаки фонем. Поэтому ответ надо искать не в истории и сохранении порядка букв в разных письменностях, а в строении голосового аппарата людей, пользовавшихся упомянутым арамейским языком и закрепивших порядок букв алфавите. Видимо, главным фактором было удобство быстрого произношения звуков-букв в алфавитах. В связи с тем же вопросом возникает другой: не существуют ли хотя бы слабые, локальные корреляции между парами соседних букв в алфавитах и в статистиках слогов в словах?