# Порядок букв в алфавите

Tags: недопустимая-метка, историческая-грамматика, алфавит

Мне вот подумалось: а есть ли какая-то закономерность в порядке букв в алфавите? Он примерно одинаковый как для славянских, так и для западных языков (и даже, если я ничего не путаю, для арабского и иврита). Как это получилось — ведь языки формировались независимо друг от друга?
Кстати, есть версия, что русский алфавит с правильными названиями букв — это целое послание: «Азъ буки веде. Глаголъ добро есте. Живите зело, земля, и, иже како люди, мыслите нашъ онъ покои. Рцы слово твердо — укъ фърътъ херъ. Цы, черве, шта ъра юсъ яти».

Answer (score 2):

[был такой вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2)

Answer (score 0):

Для начала стоит определиться с понятиями "алфавит" и "азбука". Славянская кириллица – "азбука" получила название по первым буквам - «аз+буки». Греческое слово "алфавит" это первые буквы - «альфа+бета».

Кириллическая азбука действительно послание, но для того, чтобы правильно прочитать его, надо понять, почему некоторые буквы кириллицы не имеют цифрового обозначения и почему цифровой порядок букв «нарушен». Так буква "фита" (№ 9) находится между буквами "пси"(№ 700) и "ижица"(№ 900), а не следует за буквой "иже" (№8).